# Qt: How do I resize an image and maintain its proportions?

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-resizing

This Qt [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-imageviewer.html) shows how to resize an image contained in a dialog, so that when the dialog is resized, the image stretches accordingly.

How can I resize an image in the same way, without distorting it / keeping its proportions the same?

Of course if the width/height ratio of the dialog is different from the one of the image, I will get a "grey" area.
I found the `Qt::KeepAspectRatio` enum, but not the function to use it with.

**Update**: This is the code I am trying with:

```
QImage image(path);
QImage image2 = image.scaled(200, 200, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
QLabel *plotImg = new QLabel;
plotImg->setScaledContents(true);
plotImg->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2));
```

The image does not maintain a constant aspect ratio when the label is resized. And it looses resolution after the rescaling.

Answer (score 23):

Use the [`QImage::scaled`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#scaled) function.

```
QImage img("someimage.png");
QImage img2 = img.scaled(100, 100, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

In case you need it for `QPixmap`, [a function with the same name exists](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaled).

Comment: I updated my question, including your suggestion.

Comment: A `QLabel` will not resize the pixmap it shows unless [`scaledContents`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#scaledContents-prop) is set. Also, you may want to pass [`Qt::SmoothTransformation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#TransformationMode-enum) as the last parameter to `scaled`.

Comment: scaledContents was already in my code, I just forgot to copy it in my example. Now I fixed it. The result is still the same.

Comment: Qt::SmoothTransformation just determines the quality/algorithm the image is resized with. It has no effect on the width/height ratio.

Comment: Just don't use `scaledContents`. You can react to the [`resizeEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) of your window to reset the pixmap with a new scaled one.